# Asp.net ScriptIgnore attribute not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-5, .net-4.5, scriptignore

Here are my POCO classes:

```
public class A
{
    public int id { get; set; }

    public virtual B b { get; set; }
}

public class B
{
    public int id { get; set; }

    [ScriptIgnore]
    public virtual A a { get; set; }
}
```

I want to serialize an object of A to Json. But when I try to serialize a POCO proxy object, I keep getting circular reference exception (It works for POCO objects though). I searched through Google and found ScriptIgnore attribute should work in .Net 4.5. But I am using .Net 4.5 and apparently it's not working. Could anyone told me how to solve this?

Comment: Try using the ApplyToOverrides property  (if using .net 4.5 as indicated)   [ScriptIgnore(ApplyToOverrides = true)]

Answer (score -2):

Circular object graphs cannot be JSON serialized correct way is to make a view model of use anonymous objects ex.

```
return Json(new{A.id, A.B.id})
```

Comment: But isn't ScriptIgnore for solving this situation? And it works for POCO objects.